# angularjs callback / wait for function to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm i bit stuck with function which is assigned to the `$scope variable`.
need to wait until it's finished.

This is the **function** assigned to `$scope variable`:

```
$scope.ChooseHome = function() {
    ModalWindowService.openChooseHomeDialog($scope);
}
```

in ModalWindowService I have:

```
function openChooseHomeDialog($scope) {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: '/view/user/ChooseHomeDialog.html',
        controller: 'chooseHomeDialogController',
        windowClass: 'detail-modal-window'
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (CondoID) {
        $scope.choosenCondoID = CondoID;
    });
}
```

what I want to do is properly receive this variable '$scope.choosenCondoID' after I get it from modal in '$scope.ChooseHome' function and do some work with it.

smth like this options:

```
$scope.ChooseHome = function() {
    ModalWindowService.openChooseHomeDialog($scope).then(*do my stuff*); /
    ModalWindowService.openChooseHomeDialog($scope).success(*do my stuff*);
}
```

But it's not working, I'm getting errors like this:

```
'TypeError: (intermediate value).success is not a function'
```

Comment: As a sidenote...passing on your $scope to a service is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function openChooseHomeDialog($scope) {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    return $modal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: '/view/user/ChooseHomeDialog.html',
        controller: 'chooseHomeDialogController',
        windowClass: 'detail-modal-window'
    }).result;
}

$scope.ChooseHome = function() {
    ModalWindowService.openChooseHomeDialog($scope).then(*do my stuff*);
}
```

And...like I commented...passing on the $scope to your service is a bad idea. You should only use $scope in your controller to glue your data to the view. A service just has to do something or return something which you can use.

To complicate it a bit further..you might want to look into the controllerAs syntax as well to be future proof with your code ;)

Comment: and don't send your $scope to the service :)

Answer (score 0):

you must return your promise from openChooseHomeDialog function

```
...
return modalInstance.result.then(function (CondoID) {
  $scope.choosenCondoID = CondoID;
});
```